# Check if a certain sequence of numbers appears in an array. What's wrong with my thoughts?

Tags: python, arrays, function

I am learning the fundamentals of Python and doing some finger exercise. This one question is bogging me. I don't know where I did wrong. The question is this:

Given an array of ints, return True if the sequence of numbers 1, 2, 3 appears in the array somewhere.

My solution is:

```
def array123(nums):
  arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
  if len(nums) < 3:
    return False
  for i in range(len(nums)-2):
    if nums[i:i+3] == arr1:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

I realize that this will give me False as long as the first 3 characters, so I change it to:

```
def array123(nums):
  arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
  if len(nums) < 3:
    return False
  for i in range(len(nums)-2):
    print(nums[i:i+3])
    if nums[i:i+3] == arr1:
      return True
  return False
```

This time it works. I am wondering do I have to move the "return False" out of the sub-code section of the last if?

Thanks.

Comment: Your initial solution would immediately fail if the first the elements weren't `1, 2, 3` and return False without checking the rest of the list. Your second approach is correct. Do you have a question other than that?

Comment: No, I just felt like moving it out of the loop makes the code look a little less neat. But I guess this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
if nums[i:i+3] == arr1:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

if the condition is not met, then the function stops executing and returns `False`.

Instead, you want the function to continue executing *until* it finds a triplet which satisfies that condition.

Comment: Happy to help. Remember that you can accept an answer if you found it helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In the first solution if the first 3 ints are not what you are looking for you would stop. That's not what you want. You want to keep going and try other locations.

When you moved it out of the loop you are returning false only after you've checked all positions and none of them matched.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was wondering if there was a way to do that without moving that part out of the loop. But now I see that logically it makes much more sense to keep it out of the loop.